# Why two line "Enter their marks" is printed although i only write it to print one line?

Tags: c

It prints "Enter the marks" two times when I run it, although it is written to print only one time and then take input. Where do I need to change?

When I took out the above input "Enter the number of student" do-while loop, it works just fine.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BOOLEAN int
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
void main()
{
    int T,N;
    int markIndex,markCtrl,num,markLimit,space,Ntotal = 0,f;
    BOOLEAN markCheck = TRUE;
    char line[300];
    int marks[100];
    char* pointLine;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter the number of students\n");
        scanf("%d",&N);
        Ntotal +=  N;
        if (Ntotal > 5000)
        {
            printf("Sorry you exceeded the Limit\n");
            Ntotal = 0;
        }
    } while(!( N >= 4 && N <= 100 && N%4 == 0 ));

    do
    {
        printf("Enter their marks\n");
        fgets(line,sizeof(line),stdin);
        pointLine = line;

        while( sscanf(pointLine,"%d%n",&num,&space) > 0)
        {
            marks[markIndex++] = num;
            pointLine += space;
        }

        for (markCtrl = 0 ; markCtrl < markIndex; markCtrl++)
        {
            if(marks[markCtrl] < 0 || marks[markCtrl] >100)
            {
                markCheck = FALSE;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                markCheck = TRUE;
            }
        }
        markLimit = markIndex;
        markIndex = 0;
    } while(!( markCheck == TRUE && markLimit == N));

    for ( f = 0 ; f < markLimit  ; f++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",marks[f]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf` and `fgets` don't mix well.

Comment: use `while` loops instead of `do while` loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `\n` is left out in the input stream because of your first `scanf`.

Clear the stream after first `do...while` as below.

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }
```

Comment: Thanks bro. It works. :D  but can u explain me a little about that code? I just wanna know how it works

Comment: @YatoAki While loop reads character by character until it meets newline or it until reaches end of input.